# Mochai Chai test not running

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm learning app testing at the moment, using this course: https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/angularjs-for-test-driven-development/

I'm on lesson 2.3 where we have Mocha and Chai installed, a test folder with main.spec.js setup and gulp task setup to serve the app and tests.

When he updated his main.spec.js file with this simple describe statement:

```
describe('The Address Book App', function() {
    it ('should work', function() {
        chai.assert.isArray([]);
    });
});
```

It ran fine for him:

[image]

However here is my setup:

test/main.spec.js

```
describe('The Dashboard app', function() {
    it ('should work', function() {
        chai.assert.isArray([]);
    });
});
```

Basic markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="../app/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../app/assets/imgs/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link href="testing.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="../bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script>
        mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>
    <script src="../bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script>
        mocha.run();
    </script>
    <script src="main.spec.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However my test file isn't displaying my first test:

[image]

Gulpfile setup, same as the authors, cept PORT numbers are different:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        notify : false,
        port   : 3333,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['app'],
            routes: {
                '/bower_components' : 'bower_components'
            }
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('serve-test', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        notify : false,
        port   : 4444,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['test', 'app'],
            routes: {
                '/bower_components' : 'bower_components'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea why my first basic test isn't running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks right except the ordering. 
Just swap the

```
<script>
  mocha.run();
</script>
```

with

```
<script src="main.spec.js"></script>
```

You want to run `mocha` at the end when all your specs and setup is done.